# How to default time picker display value to zero?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1, timepicker, timespan

**Overview:**

I've added a time span control to a xaml page, the binding is set via a TimeSpan property in the related View Model. All is working fine bar the default display value on the time picker.

When I test the app, the time picker's value defaults to a high value for example 12:36. I'm aiming to set the value to 00:00 as default.

In order to set the default value I stepped down through the controls properties but don't see any property that can set the default time.

I'm thinking that the 2 way binding should mean my property value could set this value.

**Question:**

How can I set the time picker display vlaue to default to 00:00 time span?

Time Picker xaml markup:

```
<TimePicker Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Width="270"
                        Height="100"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                        Header="Parking Duration:"
                        Time="{Binding SelectedParkDuration,
                                       Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Binding property:

```
    private TimeSpan? _selectedParkDuration;
    public TimeSpan? SelectedParkDuration
    {
        get
        {
            return this._selectedParkDuration;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_selectedParkDuration != value)
            {
                _selectedParkDuration = value;
                isValidTagRequest = true;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedParkDuration");
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
private TimeSpan? _selectedParkDuration = new TimeSpan();
```

or :

```
private TimeSpan? _selectedParkDuration = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00")
```